# Joomla 2.5 check user logged in

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, joomla

How do i check if a user is logged in in Joomla 2.5? I can only seem to find code snippets for the older versions of joomla. Is it the same?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
if(JFactory::getUser()->id)
{
//user has logged in
}
```

Comment: redirect him to the login page

Comment: yes but I use a facebook login method. When the user registers I get the facebook data and insert them to the #__users table but then how can I make this user as to be logged in?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it same as before try this-

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
if($user->id!=0){
//user is logged in
}
```

Comment: have done :) because im new it doesnt let me accept for a certain amount of time!

Answer (score 2):

```
$user = JFactory::getUser()->guest;
```

If you are on **PHP 5.3**.