# Joomla 2.5 - How to correctly check if user is guest or member

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, membership

What is the best (fastest/safest/better for the long run) way to check if a member is signed in Joomla.

1# way: `$user =& JFactory::getUser();
if($user->id!=0){`

2# way: `$user =JFactory::getUser()->guest;`

or another way?

These are snippets out of a custom script to check if a user is a guest to tell him to signup and if he signed in to welcome him.

I am using Joomla 2.5

I have read on [Joomla 2.5 check user logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174556/joomla-2-5-check-user-logged-in) that some codes are different depending on the php version I am using? I am puzzled.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either assuming you're running PHP 5.3, however, if you're running anything below that, then use:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser(); 

if($user->id!=0){
    //your code goes here
}
```

Personally, I would go for the second method as it goes through the Joomla API and is a tad more thorough.

On a side note, if you do use the first method, you can remove the `&`.

Comment: Thank you Lodder once again for a good answer, would too many calls (5-7) of that if statement to check if the member is logged in cause the site to slow down? (Im displaying different content on each module based on if he is a member or not) 
Would it be better I set a value to a variable $member == true if he is logged in and do an if check to the $member variable instead of calling the Joomla API? Site is already slow as it is. :/

Comment: @StanMarsh - You **wouldn't** notice any difference in the site speed. It wouldn't make any different if you used a `$member` variable. It would still go through the Joomla API each time as you would have to define `$member` with the code in my answer

Comment: You are right and a final question would there be any difference in speed between method one and two? Also if I change servers and I run to a 5.2 server would the second example work there?

Thanks again!!

Comment: I'm, not entirely sure which one is faster, however the difference will be so small that you won't even notice it. I suppose you could run some tests to see which one gets executed first. The second example I believe will throw an error due to `instanceof` within the `getUser()` function. However I have not tested it.

Answer (score 1):

/* some information about the current logged in user is displayed, but only when the user is actually logged in. */

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();

if (!$user->guest) {
  echo 'You are logged in as:<br />';
  echo 'User name: ' . $user->username . '<br />';
  echo 'Real name: ' . $user->name . '<br />';
  echo 'User ID  : ' . $user->id . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Joomla there are two ways you can check if user is loged in

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();

if($user->guest = 1){
//User in not logged in
}
else
{
//User is logged in
}
```

Or second one is

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();

if($user->id != 0){
//User is logged in
$id = $user->id; // You can use this ID for further Use
}
else
{
//User is no logged in

}
```

I personally Prefer Second one as it fulfill two usability at same time.