# How you check loging at form submission?

Tags: php, jquery, forms

php and corder.php to save data in MySQL. 
I want public to be able to enter order on my order form but I want to check if the user is logged in when user click on Submit. So corder.php will not process the order if the user is not logged in.

```
<form action="../action/subs/corder.php/" method="post" id="ccomputer" >



 <input id="id" class="id" name="id[]" type="text"/>
 <input id="quantity" class="qty" name="quantity[]" type="text"/> 
 <input id="name-data" class="price" name="price[]" type="text"/>

 <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Order" name="submission"/>
```

Comment: I guess you got a session going that has data so you know a user is logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check in the header of the page if the user is logged in, by using session (if you use cookie, the idea is the same, you just need to change the way):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
//display form 
} else { 
//redirect to login page 
}
```

Comment: Thank you I use session and also on joomla. But the page is out of joomla system. Now I have to find how to check logged in on joomla

Comment: @user3412978, Maybe this will help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174556/joomla-2-5-check-user-logged-in

Comment: Now I am able to check login with joomla. but I am unable to save data after login or sign in

Comment: @user3412978 Please explain better what you mean. after the user login you can do all what you want, i dont understand the problem.

Comment: If user is logged in, I process the order. If not I direct the user to login page get the user to login but it just logged the user to the site it don't come back and process the form. I don't wan user to start over

Comment: @user3412978 So you can save the data fields in another session.

Comment: Here if how I do it: `<?php
        $user = JFactory::getUser();
 
        if ($user->guest) {

                header("Location: http://onlinepcdoc.com/index.php/support-center/login");
                Code to save data in the db HERE;
        } else {
 
        Code to save data in the db HERE;

        }
?>
` But after user logged it it doesn come back to cotinu with the code. Should I set another redirect on the login form?

Comment: @user3412978 When the user login, redirect him back to the order form.

Answer (score 1):

As you are dealing with login, this will use sessions. I assume you already have your sessions set up and working.

This session should have data in it allowing you to check whether a user is authorised. If not, you can assign it like this: `$SESSION['authorised'] = true;`

You can use a simple if statement before processing your form to check whether the user is logged in or not.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['authorised']) && $_SESSION['authorised'] == true)
{
     //Allow form to be processed
}
```

This needs to be on the page that the form sends the data too and not on the form itself.

Comment: Thank you can you weite an example of if statement. Session is set on the page that process

Comment: @user3412978 i gave you an answer, please read..

Comment: I've edited my answer with the if statement. In place of authorised, you can use whatever you used for the session.

Comment: How to get back to the process form after logged in or signed in? I can direct to login page but how to get my script to automatically come back and save data?

Comment: Are you asking how to send the user back to the previous page after the data has been processed? There are various ways of doing this, for example, you could use JavaScript. Personally, I would consider having the form page as the processing page.

By using `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` with submit being the name of your submit button, you can have the processing code on the same page but it will only be executed once the user presses submit.

Comment: I direct user to the login page is login is not set. But it just get the user to log on the site but user have to navigate back to the form and start over I just want the processing page to process after login

Comment: So you want to know how the user can be redirected back to the form after they have logged in? You can use `javascript:history.go(-1)` on the login page as part of your JavaScript. There are other ways but I'd say that was the easiest way to do it programmatically.

Comment: I guess I need to create another login page for that. can php url redirect on the log in page  accomplish the same result? `header("Location: http://onlinepcdoc.com/sub/corder.php");`

Comment: I am on the way to fix it the redirect back from the login form seams to work. but now I need to handle my session correctly because when it comes back entries are lost.